# Javascript hex_md5 pin number

Tags: javascript

I have the following script which ask's for a pin number, it is encrypted as md5, but when i type in any value it validates, it should only do it for 1234 or 4321,i have to run 2 different if statements as im getting the pin number from the database and using a PHP foreach statement to echo them out.

```
<script>
function pinSave()
{
    var validate=prompt("Enter your PIN","Enter your PIN");
    if (validate != '' && validate != null) {

        if (hex_md5(validate) == '81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055')
            return true;
        else
        {
            alert('The PIN you entered is not correct.');
            return false;
        }           
        if (hex_md5(validate) == 'd93591bdf7860e1e4ee2fca799911215')
            return true;
        else
        {
            alert('The PIN you entered is not correct.');
            return false;
        }           

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Encode as JSON in the PHP script. Decode as JSON in the JavaScript. Put them in an array. Look for them in said array.

Comment: You seem to be suffering from RAD disorder

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to have this validation client side, since anyone can see the request for your javascript and from there view the hex_md5 numbers of the pins you validate for.

Move this into your php code and do validation before you insert a row in the db.